# How to detect manual entry or selection in Jquery AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jsfiddle for Jquery autocomplete

https://jsfiddle.net/fp7n8em5/

I want to identify , if the text inside the autocomplete field was a **manual entry or a selected one from dropdown**

when i was debugging this , i found out that the eventype is  same for both that is **autocompletechange**

basically i need to clear some of the fields if its a manual entry and don't want to do it when its a selection

my code

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags,

  select : selectedOne,
  
  change: changedOne

});

function selectedOne()
{
alert('belongs to selectedOne')
}
function changedOne()
{
alert('belongs to changedOne')
}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you differentiate the data coming from the external source?
For example you can return an extra parmeter (ie: ID), or you can add a fixed parameter (ie: type = external).
Then, when change fires, you test the returned object, if there is the parameter, then it comes from dropdown.

Or you can set input hidden variable and then you'll test if this variable is empty.
Here is an example:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        document.formname.input_type_hidden.value = ui.item.id;
    }
});
<form name="formname"><input type="hidden" name="input_type_hidden" value=""></form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response , i cant use first Option , can u tell me more on second option ??

Comment: You can use second option in this way:
if (document.formname.input_type_hidden.value != '') { // came from source } else { //came from manual entry }